# How to comprise a list with specific conditions from a list of floats

Tags: python, python-3.x

Asking a stupid question, again. I'm trying to get a list comprised of every value that is not -1 from a list of floats and -1s. Somehow, I only get the first value out of my loops. My final task is to print out the number of entries in my new list.

```py
flist = [9.0, 5.5, 6.7, 4.3, -1, 4.8, 8.0, -1, 7.0, 6.3, 4.5, 7.75, 6.5]  
for i in flist:  
    if i != 1: 
       new_list = i
#the problem is when i tried to print out the number of entries
print(len(new_list))
```

> TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

So, I tried to make it into a list of strings, and here's what I got:

```py
flist = [9.0, 5.5, 6.7, 4.3, -1, 4.8, 8.0, -1, 7.0, 6.3, 4.5, 7.75, 6.5]  
for i in flist:  
    if i != 1: 
       new_list = i
new_list2 = map(str, new_list)
print(len(list3))
```

Now, I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: jupyter-notebook tag is not relevant here.

Comment: I'm new so mb sry. Because i was using jupyter notebook so i put it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append to a list:

```
flist = [9.0, 5.5, 6.7, 4.3, -1, 4.8, 8.0, -1, 7.0, 6.3, 4.5, 7.75, 6.5]  
new_list = []
for f in flist:
    if f != -1:
        new_list.append(f)
```

Or, use a list comprehension (the better way):

```
flist = [9.0, 5.5, 6.7, 4.3, -1, 4.8, 8.0, -1, 7.0, 6.3, 4.5, 7.75, 6.5]  
new_list = [f for f in flist if f != -1]
```

In both cases, `new_list` is

```
[9.0, 5.5, 6.7, 4.3, 4.8, 8.0, 7.0, 6.3, 4.5, 7.75, 6.5]
```

If you only need the count and not the actual list, you can do this:

```
flist = [9.0, 5.5, 6.7, 4.3, -1, 4.8, 8.0, -1, 7.0, 6.3, 4.5, 7.75, 6.5]
count = sum(1 for f in flist if f != -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = [i for i in flist if i!=-1]
```

you have not initialized the list. Also while adding items in the list you have to use `append`.